# Send Android cameraPreview data to Unity

Tags: c#, java, android, camera, unity-game-engine

I use an java android activity with unity. In android I use the Camera to get a Preview, Now I want to send this data to unity using `UnitySendMessage`, but only strings are allowed here. So I convert the `byte[]` to an `Base64` string, and in `C#` is decode it back to an `byte[]`.

I don't know what I do wrong but I only get an image of an red question mark. (Think that means that the texture did not load?)

Here is my java code:

```
    _camera = Camera.open();
    _camera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(1));

    _camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam)
        {
            String strData = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
            UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("VideoFeed", "PostFeedData", strData);
        }
    });

    Camera.Parameters parameters = _camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(480, 320);

    _camera.setParameters(parameters);
    _camera.startPreview();
```

And here is my function that receives the method:

```
    byte[] byteData = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(480,320);
    tex.LoadImage(byteData);
    renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
```

I'm doing this because the WebCamTexture from unity does not work on my Android.
And this is more fun ;)

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that your camera supports: `parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);`

The camera could send NV21 formated data, and check if `tex.LoadImage(byteDate)` knows to interpret your data (almost sure it doesn't know NV21,  <strike>maybe it doesn't even know JPEG encoded data</strike>  OK it does).

To check supported formats:

```
Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
List<Integer> formats = p.getSupportedPreviewFormats();
for(Integer format: formats){
   String strFormat = "" + format;
   switch(format.intValue()){
    case ImageFormat.JPEG: strFormat = "JPEG"; break;
    case ImageFormat.NV21: strFormat = "NV21"; break;
    case ImageFormat.RGB_565: strFormat = "RGB_565"; break;
   }
    Log.v(TAG, "preview format supported: "  + strFormat);
}
```

Comment: How can I check if my camera supports it?
And LoadImage doesn't know NV21 only JPEG and PNG.

Comment: JPEG is supported by my camera.

Comment: make a byte comparison of the bytes you send in PreviewCallback and the ones your receive.

Comment: The byte buffer in java is the same size then in c#.
But the contents I cannot check, for java makes it a string of about 10 chars and c# just returns System.byte[].

Comment: What I wanted to say is to compare that what you send is what you receive:  `strData(Android) == data (C#)` (as Strings) and `data (Android) == byteData (C#)`. For byte comparison you can check the actual numbers that are stored in arrays (data[0] == byteData[0] etc...).

Comment: Okay now I just posted the length of the strings and they both are the same. But when I print the contents The c# is smaller. Is this a bug of logCat?

Answer (score 0):

I have made another solution. I now use a SurfaceView for the camera. And I add this SurfaceView to the unity activity.

OnCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ResetData();
    _camPreview = new CameraPreview();

    TextureView texView = new TextureView(this);
    _camPreview.Init(texView);

    UnityPlayer.currentActivity.addContentView(texView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400));
}
```

When I init the camera:

```
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
{
    //Get camera
    _camera = Camera.open();
    _camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    _TextureView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400, Gravity.CENTER));
    _TextureView.setTranslationY(-100);

    //Set dummy texture
    try {
        _camera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("Unity", "Error surface");
    }

    //Get parameters
    Camera.Parameters parameters = _camera.getParameters();

    //Set JPEG
    parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);

    //Set image size
    parameters.setPreviewSize(480, 320);

    //Set new parameters
    _camera.setParameters(parameters);
    _camera.startPreview();
}
```